# Haskell and Regex - Why doesn't my function eliminateRedundantSpaces work?

Tags: regex, haskell

Haskell and Regex - Why doesn't my function eliminateRedundantSpaces work?

```
import Text.Regex
eliminateRedundantSpaces text =
 subRegex (mkRegex "\\s+") text " "
```

Answer (score 10):

`Text.Regex` uses [Posix regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), and that doesn't have the `\s` abbreviation defined (that is a perl extension that many other implementations have adopted). Instead you can use the `[:space:]` character group, eg:

```
eliminateRedundantSpaces text =
   subRegex (mkRegex "[[:space:]]+") text " "
```